Make a vertical date list by month and weeks of the year on google sheets
I am trying to make a calendar list that shows the months, week numbers, and the day numbers within the month and the weeks.  Where there is information in one column, I don't want any info in the other columns, meaning the row only has one piece of information.  Here is a spreadsheet that can be manipulated as it's a copy: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EKpSzuT0_pUytBCaga80LWExRNqDcuh2iGrV5Rg_hdA/edit?usp=sharing
I was filling this out manually, but I know that there is a way to autopopulate, but can't figure it out.  I have formulas to fill out other calendars and such, but the jumps in the info is throwing me off.


Here's one generalized approach which you may improvise on:
=let(start_,date(2024,7,1), end_,date(2024,12,31), Λ,sequence(end_-start_+1,1,start_), Σ,index(hstack(text(Λ,"mmmm"),weeknum(Λ),Λ)),
 reduce(tocol(,1),unique(index(Σ,,1)),lambda(a,c,ifna(vstack(a,c,reduce(tocol(,1),unique(filter(index(Σ,,2),index(Σ,,1)=c)),lambda(f,q,vstack(f,
 if(min(filter(Λ,weeknum(Λ)=q))=+filter(index(Σ,,3),index(Σ,,2)=q,index(Σ,,1)=c), hstack(,q,),tocol(,1)),hstack(,,filter(day(index(Σ,,3)),index(Σ,,2)=q,index(Σ,,1)=c))))))))))



Thank you so much!!  This works perfectly until I try to change it to 2025...  What am I doing wrong?  I changed the date in the 3 places I saw in the formula, but it didn't populate correctly.  What did I miss?
I updated the spreadsheet with new columns to try out the different years.  Thank you for your help with this!

Try and test out the updated formula...
